# PSD to html the size of top to bottom converted to html

Tags: html, css, psd

How should I calculate the size of top to bottom of a PSD file converted to html with css for pixel perfect. For instance in PSD the padding distance between title and top-margin is 100px but in browser it seems to be too big. Should I divide this size?

[click here to see the psd](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iwMOA.png)

Comment: Do you mean PSD = Adobe's Photo Shop Document?

Comment: Yes, I mean Adobe Photoshop Document

Comment: How do you convert the PSD to HTML?

Comment: By hand: with HTML5, CSS3, Bootstrap. In PSD the size of top to bottom is too big. Should I divide this size? Or keep it?

Comment: Sorry, I still do not understand what you are trying to do.  Did you create a mock up of your web page in Photoshop, export the individual parts of the mock and build an HTML5+CSS+Bootstrap version of the mock up and now the margins etc does not align up as expected? If so, could you provide a screen shot of what you are seeing?

Comment: I added a link to see the psd. As you can see the height of that portion is 98px. It's ok? When I converted to html and launch in browser is too big.

Answer (score 0):

Click **alt+ctrl+I** in photoshop and see your psd size. for ex if your psd size is 1600*1280 given your max width as 1600 and height as auto. to get the exact margin and padding use **grids and guides** in the photoshop which will give the exact spacing between any two divs or images or paragraph.